# Bash archiving script

Tags: bash, shell

I inherited a script at work the other day.  I know very little about the command line in general but I'm not entirely new to programming.  I am using this as an opportunity to learn...  Very little of the original code is left (so if it's all wrong, it's my fault now).  I was asked to modify it retain sub-directories so I chose to use `tar`.

The directories being archived are huge; maybe not crazy huge but definitely big.  It should be ran often enough where there aren't too many files to process.  Hopefully.  I'm not sure how concerned I should be about that yet.  It can be assumed that more than once instance of this script will never be running at the same time.

```
function archive() {
   log_dir=$1       # /home/u123/initial_files/SessLogs
   age=$2           # age of the files to process
   archive=$3       # base of the archive directory
   exclude=$4       # exclude_list of directories/files

   base_dir=${log_dir%/*}  # /home/u123/initial_files
   ftype=${log_dir##*/}    # SessLogs

   date_dir=$(make_date_string $age)

   # make the new folder in the archive with the date
   arch_dir=$archive/$ftype/$date_dir
   [ ! -d $archive/$ftype ] && ( mkdir $archive/$ftype )
   [ ! -d $arch_dir ] && ( mkdir $arch_dir )

   outfile=$arch_dir/archivelog.txt
   printf "$(date)""\n\n" >>$outfile

   printf "%s\n" "processing $ftype files..." >>$outfile
   printf "%s\n" "  - type    = $ftype"       >>$outfile
   printf "%s\n" "  - age     = $age days"    >>$outfile
   printf "%s\n" "  - log_dir = $log_dir"     >>$outfile
   printf "%s\n" "  - archive = $archive"     >>$outfile
   printf "%s\n" "  - exclude = $exclude"     >>$outfile
   printf "\n">>$outfile

   # test for valid age
   if [ $age -lt 1 ]; then
      printf "\n%s\n" "age parameter is invalid" >>$outfile
      return 0
   # test for existence of log file
   elif [ ! -d $log_dir ]; then
      printf "\n%s\n" "log directory cannot be found $log_dir" >>$outfile
      return 0
   # test for existence of exclude list
   elif [ ! -f $exclude ]; then
      printf "\n%s\n" "exclude list cannot be found $exclude" >>$outfile
      return 0
   fi

   # i hate to run the full find twice since these are very large directories... idk.
   files=$( find "$log_dir" -type f -mtime +"$age" | grep -v -f "$exclude" | wc -l )

   # no files to move...
   if [[ "$files" -eq "0" ]] ; then
      #printf "find ""$log_dir"" -type f -mtime +"$age" | grep -v -f "$exclude" | wc -l" >>$outfile
      printf \n"%s\n" "there are no files to update for $log_dir" >>$outfile
      return 0
   fi

   # save this for after tar is done
   # get directories that have old files in them and give me a unique list sorted in reverse
   cleanup=( $( find "$log_dir" -type f -mtime +"$age" | grep -v -f "$exclude" | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/' | sort -ur ) )

   # shove the files in a .tar into the archive directory for this date
   find "$log_dir" -type f -mtime +"$age" | grep -v -f "$exclude" | sort -r \
        | tar vciPhf "$arch_dir"/archive.tar --remove-files --same-owner --atime-preserve --files-from - 1>&2>>$outfile

   if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
      printf "\n%s\n" "process stopped for $ftype because of errors with .tar" >> $outfile
      return 0
   fi

   # unzip the tar file in the archive directory
   sc=$( grep -o "/" <<< "$log_dir" | wc -l )
   tar xvp -C "$arch_dir" -f "$arch_dir"/archive.tar --strip-components="$sc" 1>&2>>$outfile

   printf "\n\n" >>$outfile

   # if no error: rm "$arch_dir"/archive.tar
   if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
      for dir in "${cleanup[@]}"; do
         ct=$( find $dir | wc -l )
         if [ "$ct" -eq 1 ]; then
            printf "rmdir ""$dir""\n" >>$outfile
            rmdir "$dir"
         fi
      done

      printf "\n\n%s\n" "archive successful" >>$outfile
      rm "$arch_dir"/archive.tar
      return 1
   fi 

   return 0
}

# this is entirely from the original code 
function make_date_string() {
   local -ix age=$1
   calc_time=$(expr $age \* 86400)
   date_calc=`eval "perl -e 'print scalar localtime( time - $calc_time ) . \"\n\";'"`
   final_date=`date +%Y-%m-%d --date="$date_calc"`
   echo $ftype"_"$final_date  # creates date string 
}

# a settings file will be read in... it's just this way for testing right now
archive '/home/u123/initial_files/SrcFiles' 7 '/home/u123/ArchiveFiles' '/home/u123/exclude_list'
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please indicate what exactly you did inherit (it is not subject to review per CR charter), and what is your contribution to be reviewed.

Comment: I pretty much stated that (I thought clearly) in the post.  The only thing left over is the `make_date_string` function.

Comment: the original file was the date thing and a parameter form of (not verbatim) `find ./stuff -type f -mtime +N -exec mv {} \;` It needed to use an exclude list and keep sub-directory structure.  And logging, which I'm doing now.

Comment: @vnp I disagree. OP is clearly responsible for maintaining all of the code.

Comment: I mean... I keep debating on whether I should post a portion of the original to prove everything is mine but that date part. But I ***really*** don't feel comfortable posting someone else's work for any reason.  With comments and whitespace removed, including the date stuff, Egyptian brackets - the original function was 12 lines long and used global variables.

Comment: If this is merely a log rotation script, why not use something like `logrotate`? No need to reinvent the wheel. If you have the chance to, get rid of boilerplate code and replace it with well-tested and maintained existing solutions.

Comment: @IngoBürk - like I said... I barely do command line things.  I can move about and inefficiently search but I have no idea what I'm doing.  You should have seen what I tried to do (or reinvent) before I got to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this:

> ```
> arch_dir=$archive/$ftype/$date_dir
> [ ! -d $archive/$ftype ] && ( mkdir $archive/$ftype )
> [ ! -d $arch_dir ] && ( mkdir $arch_dir )
> ```

to this:

```
[ -d $arch_dir ] || mkdir -p $arch_dir
```

That is:

- The `-p` flag of `mkdir` will make it create all intermediary directories as necessary
- No need to put `(...)` around the `mkdir`
- Using `... ||` instead of `! ... &&` is shorter, and perhaps even more natural too

---

> ```
> printf "$(date)""\n\n" >>$outfile
> ```

First of all, unless you have a good reason, don't use a `$(...)` subshell to capture the output of a command just to print it. Use the output directly:

```
date >>$outfile
```

Secondly, if a simple `echo` without parameters is enough, I would use that instead of a `printf`. If you need any of the flags of `echo`, then it's better to use `printf`, as it's more portable. For printing a blank line, I'd use `echo`.

---

Redirecting many lines to `$outfile` like this feels a bit repetitive:

> ```
> printf "%s\n" "processing $ftype files..." >>$outfile
> printf "%s\n" "  - type    = $ftype"       >>$outfile
> printf "%s\n" "  - age     = $age days"    >>$outfile
> printf "%s\n" "  - log_dir = $log_dir"     >>$outfile
> printf "%s\n" "  - archive = $archive"     >>$outfile
> printf "%s\n" "  - exclude = $exclude"     >>$outfile
> printf "\n">>$outfile
> ```

A better way would be:

```
{
    printf "%s\n" "processing $ftype files..." 
    printf "%s\n" "  - type    = $ftype"       
    printf "%s\n" "  - age     = $age days"    
    printf "%s\n" "  - log_dir = $log_dir"     
    printf "%s\n" "  - archive = $archive"     
    printf "%s\n" "  - exclude = $exclude"     
    printf "\n"
} >> $outfile
```

As mentioned earlier, an even better way would be rewriting these with simple `echo`, for example:

```
echo "processing $ftype files..."
```

Finally, since you have many lines appending to `$outfile`,
it might be best to create a helper function for it.

---

> ```
> if [[ "$files" -eq "0" ]] ; then
> ```

When using `[[ ... ]]`, you don't need to quote variables on the left side.
You also don't need to quote barewords like "0". So this is enough:

```
if [[ $files == 0 ]] ; then
```

---

This probably doesn't do what you expect:

> ```
> tar xvp -C "$arch_dir" -f "$arch_dir"/archive.tar --strip-components="$sc" 1>&2>>$outfile
> printf "\n\n" >>$outfile
>
> # if no error: rm "$arch_dir"/archive.tar
> if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
> ```

`$?` is the exit code of the last command. In this case the `printf`,
and I'm guessing that you're in fact really interested in the `tar` instead.
If you want to act on the exit code of the `tar`, then you can either use the `||` operator right after it, or save the exit code, for example:

```
tar xvp -C "$arch_dir" -f "$arch_dir"/archive.tar --strip-components="$sc" 1>&2>>$outfile
tar_exit=$?
printf "\n\n" >>$outfile

# if no error: rm "$arch_dir"/archive.tar
if [ $tar_exit = 0 ]; then
```

And no need to quote `$?` as it's always a number, never blank, never contains spaces.

---

Copy-paste your code to http://www.shellcheck.net/# and it will point out a couple of more things that you should fix.

Comment: thanks for that link...!  Ok, so... a lot of things said don't use echo because it is inconsistent (which I was surprised by).  Also, when I write things, my brain can't handle the fact a naked command (like without backticks or - don't kill me - the jquery looking notation) is syntactically correct and will be executed.

Comment: i knew `$?` was something for the last command... but for some unknown reason I didn't consider `printf` a real command... in my head.  I would have never caught that.

Comment: About `echo` versus `printf`, as I explained above, if all you need is `printf 'something\n'` then use the simpler `echo 'something'`, if you need anything more sophisticated then use `printf`

Comment: yeah... I've worked with php before.  Seems about the same.  I came across several things like this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/82330 while searching commands and stuff.  It doesn't really matter; I would have to assume none of the issues listed at that link would affect the (simple) things I am writing right now.  All the servers I use have the same rehl version anyway.